# Add new Object with generate new id of field

Tags: java

I have list:

```
private List<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();
```

My `Day` object:

```
public class Day implements Identifiable {
    private Integer id;
    private byte isHoliday;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I added a new `Day` object like:

```
Day day = new Day();
day.setHoliday(1);
days.add(day);
```

How to make, that at adding of a new element, field `id` set automatically, which equal to the previous element + 1?
Maybe I can use Java 8 Streams?

Comment: It might be easiest to make a wrapper around `List<Day>` and have a method `addDay` which does what you want.

Comment: What for do you use the `id` field?

Comment: The actual requirement for this is not clear (and it sounds silly tbh). Do you want the id to contain the position in the list? Then what if it gets added to another list? Or should all `Day`s have a unique id? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AtomicInteger() - it is thread safe.

```
 public class Day implements Identifiable {
  private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
  private int id;
  private byte isHoliday;

  public Day() {
    this.id = count.incrementAndGet(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Just new AtomicInteger ();
and if we want to start from 0, then getAndIncrement ().

Answer (score 1):

Use a static variable say `oldId` to store the previous `id`. Change your `Day` class to:

```
public class Day implements Identifiable {
    private static Integer oldId = 0;
    private Integer id;
    private byte isHoliday;

    public Day() {
        this.id = oldId + 1;
        oldId++;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: The OP want `that at adding of a new element`, not at constructing the object.

Comment: I think this can be reduced to `this.id=oldId++` and the constructor probably should be `public`

Comment: @AyushGupta, I can't use constructor, It's object is POJO without constructor

Comment: @All_Safe this is the default constructor which gets called anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static member and a constructor:

```
public class Day implements Identifiable {
  static private int maxId = 0;
  final private Integer id;
  private byte isHoliday;

  public Day() {
    this.id = maxId;
    maxId++;
  }
}
```

Every time you create a new instance of Day its id member is set to the value of maxId and then maxId is incremented.

Making "id" final is a good idea since it is used to identify your object.

Answer (score 1):

If you can try to use simple types rather than object-oriented ones, i.e. instead of Integer to int.

```
public class Day {
    private static int serial = 0; //static means that this is a common field (the same place in memory) for all created objects.
    private final int id; //final means that another value / object can not be assigned to this reference after initializing in the constructor.

    public Day() {
        id = serial++;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```